# Small Screen Notice in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently programming an app in JS that requires a large screen (at least a tablet) and I'm using CSS @media queries to disable the app on small screens. here is my code for that.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<...normal header stuff>
<p class="smallscreen">Sorry, your screen is too small for this. Try a tablet or computer! <br/> If your device is big enough, make sure it is in landscape mode!</p>
</head>
<body>
<...my app>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
body { display: none; }
.smallscreen { display: block; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
.smallscreen { display: none; }
}
```

This works fine for hiding the body content when the screen is too small, but for some reason I can't seem to get the small screen notice to show when the screen is too small.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You are setting body display to none. Nothing will show if you hide the body

Comment: `<p>` inside of `<head>` tag? Wait, that's illegal

Comment: @sinanspd Not even if my `<p>` element is in the `<head>`? Is there a suitable alternative without wrapping the entire app in a `<div>`?

Comment: head is for metadata about the page. Nothing in head will render. as @HaoWu mentioned you can not have that there. There is absolutely nothing wrong with wrapping content in a div. Alternatively you can inject new content with JS but it is an overkill in this situation

Comment: @sinanspd Without any CSS, it renders in the head fine. I guess I'll just wrap my app in a div though. Thanks

Comment: @Dai The website is actually **unusable** with a small screen, as the on-screen-keyboard would cover up all of the needed buttons.

Comment: @ElijahReardon there are small-screen devices with external keyboards - and whenever the OSK is on-screen users can still scroll the viewport.

Comment: Yes apparently it does. It is probably an oversight. It shouldn't. And you shouldn't do it. CSS specifically applies to body, that is why you can not apply it. Putting elements in the head, might be one of the worst practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write `<p>` tag on `<head>`. `<head>`is only for metadata.

You may make a container in a `<div>`, which contains all components except the warning message.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
        #mainCont { display: none; }
            .smallscreen { display: block; }
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
            .smallscreen { display: none; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="smallscreen">Sorry, your screen is too small for this. Try a tablet or computer! <br/> If your device is big enough, make sure it is in landscape mode!</p>
    <div id="mainCont">
        app
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of putting everything in the body, you could create two separate sections (one for displaying normally, and one for displaying when the screen is too small).

```html
<section class="normal">
   <!-- Your main content here -->
</section>
<section class="small-screen-warning">
  <p class="smallscreen">Sorry, your screen is too small for this. Try a tablet or computer! <br/> If your device is big enough, make sure it is in landscape mode!</p>
</section>
```

Also, as mentioned, putting a paragraph element within `<head></head>` will cause problems. Put everything visual in the `<body></body>` tags.

There may be a valid reason for displaying no functionality on a smaller screen, but this could be very irritating for users. Generally it is much better to adapt the interface through CSS, or remove components to simplify it. Desktop-style user interfaces are a great way to keep traffic away from one's website. Adaptive design is a main goal of today's website interface designs.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because we should not be encouraging or enabling the OP’s downright user-hostile design decisions when better alternatives exist.

Comment: @Dai I agree that he should create a responsive website, but there may be a specific reason why the application will not support mobile. I added a note to the OP stating this.